# Adding additional metadata in WSDL file

Tags: java, soap, soap-client

I have multiple XSDs and have a WSDL file using those XSDs. But we need to add 2-3 variables without modifying the WSDL. Is there any chance to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the .xsd files via a URL in the **schema** node (versus explicitly declaring the contents of the xsd in the node), then you can easily update the .xsd at the location referenced in the WSDL without needing to modify the WSDL.

That being said, you possibly would then need to update any existing references for anything using that WSDL/XSD combination to make sure it has the new fields available.